# Validation not returning errors Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to validate input fields on a project I'm working on. It has not been returning the validation errors. Also each time I remove the validation and I attempt to submit the form data after filling it, it returns an undefined index error.

This is my Controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\staffLogin;
use Validator;
use App\Country;
use App\Category;
use App\User;
use App\Resume;
use Image;
use Auth;
use Session; 
use DB;


class EnrolController extends Controller
{
    public function home(){
        $title = 'home';

        return view('staff.home');
    }

    public function profile(Request $request){
        $title ='profile';

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $user_name = Auth::user()->name;
        $user_email = Auth::user()->email;
        $userDetails = User::find($user_id);

        if($request->isMethod('post')){
            $data = $request->all();
            // echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;
            $data = request()->validate([
                'category_id' => 'required',
                // 'firstname' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u|max:255',
                // 'lastname' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u|max:255',
                'age' => 'required',
                'phone' => 'required',
                'gender' => 'required',
                'address' => 'required',
                'country' => 'required',
                'image' => 'required',
                'cv' => 'required',
                'experience' => 'required',
                'education' => 'required',
                'salary' => 'required',
                'employment_type' => 'required',
                'summary' => 'required',
            ]);

                $resume = new Resume;
                $resume->user_id = $user_id;
                $resume->user_name = $user_name;
                $resume->user_email = $user_email;
                $resume->category_id = $data['category_id'];
                $resume->age = $data['age'];
                $resume->gender = $data['gender'];
                $resume->address = $data['address'];
                $resume->country = $data['country'];
                $resume->phone = $data['phone'];
                // $resume->image = $data['image']->store('uploads/passport');
                // $resume->image = $data['cv']->store('uploads/cv');

                    // Upload Passport
                    if($request->hasFile('image')){
                        $image_tmp = $request->image;
                        if ($image_tmp->isValid()) {
                            // Upload Images after Resize
                            $extension = $image_tmp->getClientOriginalExtension();
                            $fileName = rand(111,99999).'.'.$extension;
                            $large_image_path = 'images/uploads/passport/large'.'/'.$fileName;
                            $medium_image_path = 'images/uploads/passport/medium'.'/'.$fileName;
                            $small_image_path = 'images/uploads/passport/small'.'/'.$fileName;

                            Image::make($image_tmp)->save($large_image_path);
                            Image::make($image_tmp)->resize(600, 600)->save($medium_image_path);
                            Image::make($image_tmp)->resize(300, 300)->save($small_image_path);

                            $resume->image = $fileName; 

                        }
                    }  

                    // Upload CV
                    if($request->hasFile('cv')){
                        $image_tmp = $request->cv;
                        if ($image_tmp->isValid()) {
                            // Upload Images after Resize
                            $extension = $image_tmp->getClientOriginalExtension();
                            $fileName = rand(111,99999).'.'.$extension;
                            $large_image_path = 'images/uploads/cv/large'.'/'.$fileName;
                            $medium_image_path = 'images/uploads/cv/medium'.'/'.$fileName;
                            $small_image_path = 'images/uploads/cv/small'.'/'.$fileName;

                            Image::make($image_tmp)->save($large_image_path);
                            Image::make($image_tmp)->resize(600, 600)->save($medium_image_path);
                            Image::make($image_tmp)->resize(300, 300)->save($small_image_path);

                            $resume->cv = $fileName; 

                        }
                    }  

                $resume->education = $data['education'];
                $resume->experience = $data['experience'];
                // $resume->salary = $data['salary'];
                if(!empty($data['salary'])){
                    $resume->salary = $data['salary'];
                }else{
                    $resume->salary = ''; 
                }
                $resume->employment_type = $data['employment_type'];
                $resume->verification = $data['verification'];
                // if(empty($data['verification'])){
                //     $verification='0';
                // }else{
                //     $verification='1';
                // }
                $resume->summary = $data['summary'];
                // if(!empty($data['summary'])){
                //     $resume->summary = $data['summary'];
                // }else{
                //     $resume->summary = ''; 
                // }
                $resume->status = $data['status'];
                // if(empty($data['status'])){
                //     $status='0';
                // }else{
                //     $status='1';
                // }
                // $resume->save();

                return redirect()->back()->with('flash_message_success', 'Resume Added!!!');
            }


        // if($request->isMethod('post')){
        //  $data = $request->all();
            // echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;

        $countries = Country::get();

        $categories = Category::where(['parent_id' => 0])->get();

        $categories_drop_down = "<option value='' selected disabled>Select</option>";
        foreach($categories as $cat){
            $categories_drop_down .= "<option value='".$cat->id."'>".$cat->name."</option>";
            $sub_categories = Category::where(['parent_id' => $cat->id])->get();
            foreach($sub_categories as $sub_cat){
                $categories_drop_down .= "<option value='".$sub_cat->id."'>&nbsp;&nbsp;--&nbsp;".$sub_cat->name."</option>";    
            }
        }



        return view('staff.add_profile')->with(compact('staffDetails', 'categories_drop_down', 'countries'));
    }

    public function viewProfile() {

        $resume = Resume::get();

        return view('staff.view_profile')->with(compact('resume'));
    }

}
```

This is my form

```
@section('content')

    <div class="section wb">
        <div class="container">

            @if(Session::has('flash_message_success'))
                <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button> 
                        <strong>{!! session('flash_message_success') !!}</strong>
                </div>
            @endif
            @if(Session::has('flash_message_error'))
                <div class="alert alert-error alert-block" style="background-color:#f4d2d2">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button> 
                        <strong>{!! session('flash_message_error') !!}</strong>
                </div>
            @endif  

            <div class="section-title text-center">
                <h3>My Profile {{ Auth::user()->name }}</h3>
            </div><!-- end title -->

        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="addprofile" id="addprofile" method="post" action="{{ url('/add-resume') }}">{{ csrf_field()}}

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category_id">Category</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="category_id" name="category_id">
            <option value="">Select Category</option>
                <?php echo $categories_drop_down; ?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="age">Age</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="age" id="age" placeholder="Age" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender">Gender</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="gender" name="gender" >
                <option value="not specified">Select Gender</option>
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="address" id="address" rows="3" ></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="country">Country</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="country" name="country" >
            <option value="">Select Country</option>
                @foreach($countries as $country)
                <option value="{{ $country->country_name }}">{{ $country->country_name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="education">Education Level</label>
            <select name="education" class="form-control" >
                  <option value="" selected disable>Select Education Level</option>
                  <option value="High School/Secondary School">High School/Secondary School</option>
                  <option value="Diploma">Diploma</option>
                  <option value="Bachelors' Degree">Bachelors' Degree</option>
                  <option value="Masters">Masters</option>
                  <option value="Doctorate">PhD</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="experience">Experience</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="3" name="experience" id="experience" placeholder="Experience" ></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="salary">Salary</label>
            <input type="phone" class="form-control" name="salary" id="salary" placeholder="Expected Base Salary" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="employment_type">Employment Type</label>
            <select name="employment_type" class="form-control" >
                  <option value="" selected disable>Select Employment Type</option>
                  <option value="Any">Any</option>
                  <option value="Part Time">Part Time</option>
                  <option value="Full Time">Full Time</option>
                  <option value="Freelance">Freelance</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="image">Passport (*jpg, *png, *jpeg)</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file" id="image" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="cv">A Page CV (*jpg, *png, *jpeg)</label>
            <input type="file" name="cv" class="form-control-file" id="cv" >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="summary">Summary</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" rows="3" name="summary" id="summary" placeholder="Summary" ></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>


 </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

This is my route web.php

```
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

    // Route::get('/', function () {
    //     return view('index');
    // });


    Route::get('/', 'frontController@index');

    Route::get('/home', 'EnrolController@home');


    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/admin', 'AdminController@login');

    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/about', 'frontController@about');

    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/contact', 'frontController@contact');

    // Users Login/Register Page
    Route::get('/login-register','UsersController@userLoginRegister');

    // Staff Register Page
    Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/staff-register','StaffController@register');

    Route::match(['get','post'],'/forgot-password','UsersController@forgotPassword');

    Route::get('/resume/{url}','ResumeController@resumes');

    // Resume Detail Page
    Route::get('/resume/{id}','ResumeController@resume');

    // Users Register Form Submit
    Route::post('/user-register','UsersController@register');

    // Confirm Account
    Route::get('confirm/{code}','UsersController@confirmAccount');

     // Confirm Account
     Route::get('home/confirm/{code}','StaffController@confirmAccount');

    // Users Login Form Submit
    Route::post('/user-login','UsersController@login');

    // Staff Login Form Submit
    Route::post('/staff-login','StaffController@login');

    // Staff forgot password
    Route::match(['get','post'],'/staff-forgot-password','StaffController@forgotPassword');

    // Staff logout
    Route::get('/staff-logout','StaffController@logout');

    // Users logout
    Route::get('/user-logout','UsersController@logout');

    Route::match(['get','post'],'/staff-forgot-password','StaffController@forgotPassword');


    Route::group(['middleware' => ['stafflogin']], function () {
        Route::get('/staff/dashboard', 'StaffController@dashboard');
        Route::get('/staff/settings','StaffController@settings');
        Route::get('/staff/check-pwd','StaffController@chkPassword');
        Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/staff/update-pwd','StaffController@updatePassword');

        Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/add-profile','EnrolController@profile');
        Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/view-profile','EnrolController@viewProfile');

        Route::match(['get','post'],'/add-resume','EnrolController@profile');
        Route::get('/admin/view-profile','ResumeController@viewProfile');
        Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/admin/edit-resume/{id}','ResumeController@editResume');        

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
use use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
//...
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'category_id' => 'required',
     ...
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
     return redirect()->back()
         ->withErrors($validator)
         ->withInput();
}

$data = $validator->validated();
```

Comment: I tried doing it that way but it returns a Type error. TypeError
Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Controller::validate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in C:\wamp64\www\virtual\app\Http\Controllers\EnrolController.php on line 41

Comment: I also tried using $data = request()->validate([ ]); which worked before but still no luck

Comment: Did you tried the Validator facade ? if not check my updated answer

Comment: ErrorException Undefined index: category_id came up on using the updated answer with the Validator facade

Comment: I missed this instruction `$data = $validator->validated();` . Hope it solves the issue

Comment: How do I solve 'ErrorException Undefined index: verification'  because it seems thats the only hurdle left for me to cross

Comment: `$resume->verification = $data['verification'] ?? Null;`